# Changing part of a URL and appending the URL based on specific characters jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to look at a href in a page and see if a certain bit of text is in the URL, if it is i need to change it to something else, then append a location to the end.

if the link contains "ice/app?service=page&page=probrowse"

ex: http://www.google.com/**ice/app?service=page&page=probrowse**&cat=1&year=2011

I need to change it to "club/probrowse.htm?"

ex: http://www.google.com/club/probrowse.htm?cat=1&year=2011

I am currently running the script below which takes into consideration ? and & in the URL and appending a location to the href.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        jQuery('a').attr('href', function() {
                return (this.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) ? this.href + "&location=/abc/123" : this.href + "?location=/abc/123";
           });

    });
</script>
```

I ran into some other bumps due to the fact I am ingesting information from another site and need to make some minor URL changes.

The overall goal is to change

google.com/ice/app?service=page&page=probrowse&cat=1&year=2011

into

google.com/club/probrowse.htm?cat=1&year=2011&location=/abc/123

Comment: Wowzers.  Forgive me for asking this if you have already thought of this, but are you really sure that using JavaScript to hack the URLs is the best approach?  Typically just doing a find/replace on the source files would be better.  Additionally, web indexing services (ie. Google) see the URL as it gets rendered, not as it will be after the hack.

Comment: I am not concerned with the web indexing. It's kind of complicated in regards to the way the data is being brought into the page. The locations appending works great, I am just looking to change links for the series of "next pages" at the bottom of a list being brought in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is what you are looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
    var substr = 'ice/app?service=page&page=probrowse';
    var newstring = 'club/probrowse.htm?';
    jQuery("a").each(function(){
        if(this.href.indexOf(substr) != -1){
            var newHref = this.href;
            newHref = newHref.replace(substr, newstring);
            newHref += '&location=/abc/123';
            newHref = newHref.replace('?&','?');
            this.href = newHref;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I took what you did, and made a small adjustment. and added an else statement to cover the other links on the page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
        var substr = 'ice/app?service=page&page=probrowse';
        var newstring = 'club/probrowse.htm?';
        jQuery("a").attr('href', function(){
            if(this.href.indexOf(substr) != -1){
                var newHref = this.href;
                newHref = newHref.replace(substr, newstring);
                newHref += '&location=/abc/123';
                newHref = newHref.replace('?&','?');
                this.href = newHref;
} else {
        return (this.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) ? this.href + "&location=/abc/123" : this.href + "?location=/abc/123"; 
    }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: That was unintentional. I meant to accept yours. I just added mine to show my final result for others. I corrected it and accepted your answer.